# Vuejs jquery compilation stuck

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I m creatin a website in vue js, but when i use external jquery.min.js and custom.js(a custom script ) in main.js
like this

```
import "./assets/js/style.css"
import "./assets/js/jquery.min.js"
import "./assets/js/custom.js"
```

the compilation stuck at jquery.min.js,
when i remove jquery.min.js compilation successful,  i installed jquery from npm but no use, the custom script uses the jquery so i can't remove, any help

Comment: [Tried googling](https://bytutorial.com/blogs/vuejs/how-to-use-jquery-in-vuejs-2) your question?

Comment: yes, tried some methods, not resolved yet